# How to auto refresh src link every 5 Seconds from other .php link

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I auto refresh src link every 5 Seconds to img link from other.php link to index.php src link??

In **index.php**

```
<img id="img1" class="imgNews" src =https://example.com/car.jpg">
```

In **other.php**

```
<span id =link1>https://example.com/other.jpg</span>
```

Expected result in index.php

```
<img id="img1" class="imgNews" src =https://example.com/other.jpg">
```

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` and `jquery ajax` with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="loader">
  <img class="imgNews" src="https://example.com/car.jpg">
</div>

<script src="//www.antradar.com/nano.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    ajxpgn('loader','other.php?');
},5000);
</script>
```

Change your other.php content to show the image directly:

```
<img src="some_other_image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:"other.php",  
    dataType : 'html',
    success:function(response) {
      $('#img1').prop('src', $(response).filter('#link1').html());
    }
  });
},5000);
```

You can use filter to get element from ajax returned html.